# Java HttpsServer: Connections timing out after first sucessfull request

Tags: java, curl, https, keep-alive

I'm trying to add a small webserver into my Java program to serve internal data to a grafana server for plotting. I came accross the internal HttpsServer Class and set it up to the point where it does serve the wanted content.

Now I'm testing the programm with curl on the commandline. It serves the first request as expected. But if i try to run my curl command a second time, I'm running into a timeout. Then i need to kill my java app and restart it. Just so it stops working again after one successfull request.

EDIT: I tried removing the SSL bits. Plain HTTP does not seem to be suffering from the same problems. Also adding --http1.0 to the curl command seems to be working...

What i tried:

- changed backlog parameter in constructor - no change
- closing the OutputStream the Connection / Exchange. I made sure of that by trying to use
  try/catch/finally.
- "always consume the complete InputStream" - no change
- using a threadpool of n => connection hangs on n+1 request
- add Thread.getCurrentThread().stop() at the end of the Exchange Handler.
  Obviously nasty and only works on certain jvm's (Windows: no, Linux:yes)
- tried breakpoint in HttpHandler, which triggers in the first
  request but not the second. So I'm pretty sure it's a problem outside
  of my own code.
- removed my own code and made it as basic as can be. still same problem

Am I missing something? Do I need to close anything else? Maybe some weird keep-alive stuff? Maybe the socket gets not closed but can also not be reused on the second request? I'd rather not configure endless Threads (i.e. CachedThreadPool without any limits). Is HttpsServer not the right solution for me and i need to switch to something like undertow or JLHTTP?`
Thanks for your help!

```java
public class SimpleWebserver {

    private static final InetSocketAddress ADDRESS = new InetSocketAddress(8443);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Initialise the HTTPS server
            HttpsServer httpsServer = HttpsServer.create(ADDRESS, 0);
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

            // Initialise the keystore
            char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("testkey.jks");
            ks.load(fis, password);

            // Set up the key manager factory
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, password);

            // Set up the trust manager factory
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            tmf.init(ks);

            // Set up the HTTPS context and parameters
            sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            httpsServer.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext) {
                @Override
                public void configure(HttpsParameters params) {
                    try {
                        // Initialise the SSL context
                        SSLContext c = SSLContext.getDefault();
                        SSLEngine engine = c.createSSLEngine();
                        params.setNeedClientAuth(false);
                        params.setCipherSuites(engine.getEnabledCipherSuites());
                        params.setProtocols(engine.getEnabledProtocols());

                        // Get the default parameters
                        SSLParameters defaultSSLParameters = c.getDefaultSSLParameters();
                        params.setSSLParameters(defaultSSLParameters);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(SimpleWebserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });

            httpsServer.createContext("/", new SimpleHandler());
            //httpsServer.setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));
            //httpsServer.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
            httpsServer.setExecutor(null);
            httpsServer.start();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleWebserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private static class SimpleHandler implements HttpHandler {

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
            HttpsExchange httpsExchange = (HttpsExchange) he;

            try {

                try (InputStream in = httpsExchange.getRequestBody()) {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[500];
                    while (in.read(buf) != -1) {
                    }
                }

                String response = "Hello World! \r\n";
                httpsExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.getBytes().length);

                try (OutputStream os = httpsExchange.getResponseBody()) {
                    os.write(response.getBytes());
                }

            } finally {
                httpsExchange.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I use the following curl cmd to test the server:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"Testing!"}' --insecure --no-keepalive --connect-timeout 5 https://localhost:8443
```

Result (first Request):

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:8443/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using unknown / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=Unknown; ST=Unknown; L=Unknown; O=Unknown; OU=Unknown; CN=localhost
*  start date: Jul 11 19:57:54 2019 GMT
*  expire date: May 19 19:57:54 2029 GMT
*  issuer: C=Unknown; ST=Unknown; L=Unknown; O=Unknown; OU=Unknown; CN=localhost
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
* (304) (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8443
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 19
> 
* upload completely sent off: 19 out of 19 bytes
* (304) (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* (304) (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 14 Jul 2019 11:27:15 GMT
< Content-length: 15
< 
* (304) (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
Hello World! 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Second run:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:8443/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```